# Как сделать градиент, исходящий из середины?

Tags: html, css, background

Как сделать градиент, цвет которого исходит из середины?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно это не градиент, а box-shadow: inset

```css
.button {
 background-color: red;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
 width: 300px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
```